# How is Marmalade related to iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, marmalade

There are rumors that Apple rejects apps compiled against iOS SDK lower than 6.0. I am wondering how is this related to Marmalade apps? I have installed Xcode 4.5 and switched xcode-select to it. Marmalade projects correctly build. Does this solve the issue?

Comment: Marmalade SDK is already updated to work with iOS 6. Use the 6.2 version. We've successfully submitted our games using this to iTunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marmlade compiles against old version of iOS SDK. I guess it is 4.1 or 4.3

iPhone 5 screen is not supported right now. Marmalade can't distribute iOS SDK. They have frameworks with stubs functions.

```
c:\Marmalade\6.0.6\s3e\deploy\plugins\iphone\sys_libs\System\Library\Frameworks\
```

So if they used 4.1 and now they will have to support 6.0 then they will have to upgrade all these fake frameworks. It is is not automated then it could be a very big manual job. + Debugging, testing

I hope it is all about screen resolution and they will be able to supply iPhone 5 solution ASAP.

Comment: If an app is OpenGL based, this shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: All Marmalade apps are OpenGL. If you ask about IwGL vs IwGX then I do not see any difference. IwGX is just layer above IwGL.